# Estoy usando una etiqueta <a> para hacer submit en varios forms pero solo manda los datos del primero

Tags: php, html, html5

Estoy usando una etiqueta < a > para hacer submit a un formulario pero solo envia los datos del primer formulario

```html
 <?php foreach ($consulta as $valor) { ?>
                    <form action="../noticias/noticia.php" method="post" id="myform">
                        <a id="acceder-noticia" href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('myform').submit()">
                            <input type="text" style="visibility:hidden" name="etiquetas" value="<?php echo $valor['Etiqueta']; ?>">
                            <div class="card mb-3" style="border-bottom:1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.281)">
                                <h5 class="titulo-t"><?php echo $valor['Titulo_noticia']; ?></h5>
                                <img src="<?php echo $valor['Imagen']; ?>" class="card-img-top imagen-t" alt="...">
                                <div class="card-body">
                                    <p class="descp-t"><?php echo $valor['Descripcion_aviso']; ?></p>
                                    <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted"><?php echo $valor['Fecha']; ?></small></p>
                                    <input type="number" class="btn btn-outline-danger" name="codigo" value="<?php echo $valor['id']; ?>">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </form>
                <?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Es una falla con el id de tu form, y el llamado al envio del formulario, en el loop de PHP le estas asignando el mismo id a todo nuevo form, y el id debe ser unico para que te funcione bien la llamada de JavaScript, luego al hacer click en el link, estas disparando el submit, pero como el id esta duplicado o mas, solo se envia el primero, prueba agregando un contador en el loop para que el id del form tambien cambie